# How to use system.DateTime to pick a valid date from a datepicker when running test at any time

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, datepicker

I need to pick a valid date from a datepicker in my automated tests. I'm very new to C#, Selenium and Visual Studio. My current code is:

```
DriverGC.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".formElement.jsDatePicker")).Click();
DriverGC.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".datePicker_list li[data-day='25']")).Click();
```

This works ok, as long as 25 is valid for example. If I run the test say on the 26th of the month, the next available 25 is on the next month, so not valid and my test fails.

Can I put a line of code in that will use my system date, and then say +2, and then select this as the date in the datepicker, so no matter when I run the test during the month, it will always pick a valid date?

Answer (score 1):

When I understand it correctly you want to select any valid date in your datepicker, right?

I would suggest creating an Array with all valid dates first, and than randomly select one of those. This is Java code, but the C# syntax should be similar.

```
//create list of all valid elements
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("selectorForValidDates"));  

//get a random index of the list
int i = new Random().nextInt(elements.size());  

//click on valid element
elements.get(i).click();
```

It's important to have proper attributes on your elements to easily select them. Like `class="validDate"` on all dates that can be selected. This way your css-selector could look like `.datePicker_list li.validDate` which would only return the elements you can actually use.

Comment: Thaks so much for your reply, this and the other approach have both worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this syntax:

```
int currentdayOfTheMonth = DateTime.Now.Day;
string cssLocator = string.Format(".datePicker_list li[data-day='{0}']", currentdayOfTheMonth);
DriverGC.FindElement(By.CssSelector(cssLocator)).Click();
```

This code will get first the current day of the month, build the css locator and then find the element. If you want to add one day or subtract you can use the AddDays method of the DateTime.

```
int currentdayOfTheMonth = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day;
```

Comment: Thaks so much for your reply, this and the other approach have both worked!

Comment: Out of curiosity since I'm not familiar with `DateTime` and C#, what would `DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).Day` return if the current day is the last of the month?

Comment: Unfort, this will cause the test to fail, because on my date picker it doesn't automatically show valid dates in the next month. For the time being I just won't run the test on the last day of the month, but I will look to make a dev change to the date picker on the site to show valid days in the next month which would negate this issue. (A bit how Microsoft Outlook shows the calendar in the top right